# Value-dependent char on field

Tags: python, html, django

I have 2 char fields in my model named `rrb`. One has choices and another is 'sr'. When I select choice rrb as 3 I want the `sr` value to be 6. Similarly, when I choose `5`, I want the value of `sr` to be 4. How can i do that?

```
RRB = (
        ("1.4", "1.4"), 
        ("3", "3"), 
        ("5", "5"),
        ("10","10"),
        ("15","15"),
        ("20","20")
)
rrb = models.CharField(
    max_length=10,
    choices=RRB,
    default="10",
)
sr = models.CharField(default='15.36', max_length=10)
```

play.html

```
<td>RX RF Bandwidth(MHz): </td>
<td>{{form.rrb}}</td>
<td>sample Rating:</td>
<td>{{form.sr}}</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var e=document.getElementById('id_rrb');
    var s = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if(s==3){
       document.getElementById('id_sr').value=6;
    }
</script>
```

expected result:

When the choice 3 in the (rrb) choices list, the sr text field should display 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('#id_rrb').change(function(){
    var e=($(this).val());
    if(e==3)
    {
           document.getElementById("id_sr").value=6;
    }
})
</script>
```

this works.